# Add decimal to last two numbers in numeric string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following numeric string where I need to add a decimal to the last two numbers.

So

```
300000
```

Becomes

```
3000.00
```

Can someone please help me out here, which regex code should I use for this? Or should I not use regex at all for this.

Thanks

Comment: I don't have any knowledge of regex and so I have no idea where to start even.

Comment: It doesn't require regular expressions at all. Stack Overflow does require people to do research before posting questions, however.

Comment: If your input can contain mixed input, or it may be numbers and strings, you  will need a regex for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```js
var str="300000";

var resStr=str.substring(0,str.length-2)+"."+str.substring(str.length-2);

document.write(resStr);
```

Comment: FWIW, `substr` accepts negative indexes as offsets from the end, so `str.substr(-2)` is the same as `str.substring(str.length-2)`.

Comment: If the string is not numeric, the result will be unexpected.

Comment: The question is about numeric string.

Answer (score 4):

You can capture 2 groups of digits and then add a period. This regex will make sure you only match numbers with a minimum length of 3 digits, and it will insert a period before the last two:

```js
var re = /\b(\d+)(\d{2})\b/; 
var str = '300000';
var subst = '$1.$2'; 
var result = str.replace(re, subst);
alert(result);
```

See [example](https://regex101.com/r/wO4kX5/1).

Answer (score -2):

```
var inFloat = parseFloat("10").toFixed(2);
console.log(inFloat);
```

Comment: It wont work its adding the two Precision to the current value but the requirement is  300000 to be 3000.0o